Is there a function that can change the file path of the components entry in installshield from "BEHAVIOR AND LOGIC/InstallScript"?
enter image description here
Both the file path from which files are imported during installation
enter image description here
and the file path after installation.
i can't find... please help!
Previously, after adding all "components" along the folder path, the feature was renamed to implement the installation along the folder path, but the method is too inefficient.
